# How to get value from datalist in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, datalist

I am trying to retrieve a value from a `DataList` to use it in some formula

so I tried this code and I included it in the `OnClick` button event:

```
float fQ = float.Parse(Qtytb.Text);
float ftotal;
float fitem = float.Parse(pricelst.SelectedItem.ToString());
ftotal = fQ * fitem;
totaltb.Text = ftotal.ToString();
```

But it gave me null pointer exception at this point

```
( float fitem = float.Parse(pricelst.SelectedItem.ToString()); )
```

How can I get that to work?

Comment: You should check that `pricelst.SelectedIndex >= 0`.

Answer (score 1):

add below validation

```
if(pricelst.SelectedItem != null)
{
  //your code....

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if either `pricelst`, or `pricelst.SelectedItem` is null and handle these cases appropriately. For example, you could use `float.TryParse(...)` or the null coalescing operator `??`.

As an example:

Given the class

```
   private class Foo
   {
       public string SelectedItem { get; set; }
   }
```

check for null like this:

Foo pricelst = new Foo();

```
    float fitem;

    if(float.TryParse(pricelst.SelectedItem, out fitem))
    {
        // set defaults here
        fitem = 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var selectedItemValue =  pricelst.SelectedItem == null ? "0" : pricelst.SelectedItem.ToString();
var selectedItemFloat = float.Parse(selectedItemValue);
var fQ = float.Parse(Qtytb.Text);
var ftotal = fQ * selectedItemFloat;
totaltb.Text = ftotal.ToString();
```

Comment: it give me " 0 " as a total !! is there any other way to get the value of an element in the datalist ?

Comment: @SuperGirl that doesn't make sense... that means that pricelst.SelectedItem is null, in other words it is not set. Maybe you should show the code... where you think you are setting it to a value.